# How to Exclude Certain Full Backups in Netbackup as Basis for Differential?

Tags: backup, netbackup

I run a full backup of certain servers every month to a tape for off site-backup in Netbackup 6.0.  The off-site backup is a different schedule and uses a different Volume Pool.  When this off-site backup is run, I also still have the normal weekly full backups run.

My problem is that when the differential backups runs during the week, they use the off-site tapes as their base full backup.  Oh can I change this behavior so the off site backup is not used as a basis for the differentials?

Or, how does Netbackup know which full to use as the basis  for the differential?  Maybe if I set up another policy I can get the behavior I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told on a symantec netbackup forum that putting it in a different policy would solve this issue, but I have yet verify this...

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by making all backups to disk then duplicating the backups I wanted to tape, sometimes several different tape pools (off-site, on-site long term storage, etc).  I had to write some custom scripts to manage this, but it worked pretty well after everything was up and running.

Comment: This would be to much for what I am trying achieve I think ...

Comment: I agree - it is a bit of work and it's annoying that NB doesn't offer better tools to manage the duplication of backup images, but it also solves a bunch of other problems, and NB actually works very nicely with disk-based backup images.  Especially given that there aren't any license issues with disk based backups and disk based storage is so cheap, it does make a nice architecture if you start with it in mind. (clients -> disk -> tape(s))

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to do duplication which requires acquiring NetBackup Vault, I strongly suggest running your incremental backups immediately before the monthly full backups.  This will let you get as close to undisturbed backups as possible.

Other options include having NetBackup make two simultaneous copies of it's full backup on the day you want your montly off site copy to be made.  Leaving one copy in the local media pool and having one written to the off site pool.  This of course presumes you have more than one tape drive.

Comment: If you're not afraid of scripting and using the CLI tools you don't *need* vault but vault makes it far easier.